# A scientist catches 8 butterflys II

Tags: probability

A scientist catches 8 butterflies,each of which may appear in one of 4  different colors:

- White
- Brown
- Red
- Black

  **another similar question not the same it's another section** with the same experiment ,what is the probability that **the fifth butterfly is the first red**??

My attempts:
 $(3/4)^4*(1/4)=0.0791$  **or** $c(4,3)3^4/4^5=0.3164$
the optional answers are :

- $0.25$
- $0.079$
- $0.396$
- $0.316$

  **what is the right answer ??**

Comment: The first version of this question (which was virtually identical) was put on hold because it showed no efforts.  The comments and answers to that one apply just as well here.

Comment: Being the one who answered that previous version (and made effort attempting to edit it properly for the OP), I tend to agree with @lulu.

Comment: Hi  there ,I'm asking what's the heck going here??you have told me to put the other question in a separate post.it's actually a main question with multiple sections,it has 4 sections I've tried to post two of them.

Comment: I want to thank barak manos despite all the misunderstandings ,barak ,I admit he has helped me , the second section could make me know that my solutions are right or wrong.I've sent my solutions to the Uni.two days ago so I wanted to be calm and may fix something at the last minute.now I can't change anything

Comment: For the next time what do you want me to do with a question with multiple sections??to post in one place or separated???

Comment: there is no attempt to show what you have done. Hence, downvote.

Comment: The Math.SE site has a central purpose to promote learning of math at all levels, and to do so we seek to curate excellent content in both Questions and Answers.  This is not the same as trying to assure everyone gets their homework done correctly.  There may be other resources available to you for that kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the answer to your previous (now closed) question as reference.

---

The total number of sequences is $4^8$.

The number of desired sequences is $3^4\cdot1\cdot4^3$:

- For the first $4$ places, there are $3$ optional colors, hence $3^4$ options
- For the fifth place, there is $1$ optional color, hence $1$ option
- For the last $3$ places, there are $4$ optional colors, hence $4^3$ options

Hence the probability is $\frac{3^4\cdot1\cdot4^3}{4^8}\approx0.079$.

Comment: now your solutions and mine are with the same results but with totally different ways I have used the probability of 1/4 ,and random variables ,like a die with 4 faces I hope that those are the correct results in my school ,I'll update you later,thanks a lot.,if the solutions are wrong I may lose 20 marks  at least,5 for every section.